# Submit form via AJAX but keep client side validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, forms

In my HTML code I have required fields and regular expression pattern checking using HTML5 attributes. I want to submit my data to my server via AJAX but I have to use  e.preventDefault();

Using that, disables all the HTML5 attributes like "required" and "type=email" and the built in HTML5 client side check. Basically the user can just submit an empty form.

Is there a way to make HTML5 first check if the attributes i specified are met, then e.preventDefault from submitting so i can manually submit via AJAX?

```js
$("input[type='submit']#input_submit").click(
  function(e) {
    //Prevents form from submitting right away:
    e.preventDefault();

    // Allows or keeps halting form submission process; returns true or false.
    validationForm();
});

function validationForm() {

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="lastname">
<p>Last Name</p>
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Letters Only" required></input>
</section>
<input id="input_submit"  type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: please add code from your html5 for have some idea of your structure.

Comment: <section id="lastname">
          <p>Last Name</p>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Letters Only" required></input>
        </section>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instead prevent the form submit from happening (instead of the button click), you will get the behaviour you want.

```
$("form#your_form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4o8nnkjy/

So in the above example, the alert only happens if the form is valid.

Comment: looked perfect to me

Answer (score 0):

You can change the submit for a button instead.

```
<input id="button" type="button">
```

Then, when the user clicks button

```
$('#button').click(function(){validationForm(input1, input2, etc);});
```

So, what have to do **validationForm** function? All you want to do with validations.

```
function validationForm(input1, input2, input3){
    //Make all your validations
    //Then, if all is correct, send the data via AJAX
 }
```